# Batch: Issues with variables while using DisableDelayedExpansion

Tags: batch-file, variables

**BACKGROUND:**
I have about 20 folders and from time-to-time individually select to run a .BAT file from within one of the folders, example complete folder path being the following:

```
G:\419065 - patreon - gotgames\' Source\ChromeLink.bat
```

To date, I've only needed to assign:

Entire folder name to VAR %FOLDER% and

End portion of the folder name to VAR %endFOLDER%.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
For %%G In ("%~dp0..") Do For %%H In (%%~nxG) Do Set "FOLDER=%%~nxG" & Set "endFOLDER=%%H"

echo %FOLDER%
echo %endFOLDER%

start chrome "https://www.patreon.com/%endFOLDER%"
```

Checking my variables, output is shown as:

```
419065 - patreon - gotgames
gotgames
```

**PROBLEM:**
While maintaining the assignment of VAR %FOLDER%, how can I breakout and assign a VAR for each of the three pieces of the folder name (no "-" no spaces.)?

```
FOLDER
startFOLDER
midFOLDER
endFOLDER
```

Comment: Start directory is ```G:\```,  end directory is apparently ```' Source``` so the mid directory is ```419065 - patreon - gotgames```.  Anyhow, your question is unclear. Are you wanting to isolate the substrings delimited by the hyphens and space characters in the batch files grandparent directory name? Remember [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70650278/pare-down-a-variable-to-all-after-last-space#comment124897662_70650278), in a previous question of yours. You have tried to use my code but still not learned how to ask in an understandable manner.

Comment: You were correct in "wanting to isolate the substrings delimited by the hyphens and space characters in the batch files grandparent directory name." I provided a full example directory path in order to show any nested folders, and the location of said batch file within those nested folders. Yes, I should have been clearer by my delineating the grandparent directory name as the sole target. The below works perfectly and I appreciate the effort you put forth in same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[untested]

```
for %%G in (start mid end) do set "%%Gfolder="
For %%G In ("%~dp0..") Do Set "FOLDER=%%~nxG"&For %%H In (%%~nxG) Do if "%%H" neq "-" (
 if defined startfolder (
  if defined midfolder (
   Set "endFOLDER=%%H"
  ) else (
   set "midfolder=%%H"
  )
 ) else (
  set "startfolder=%%H"
 )
)
```

which should set the three variables only once, having first cleared them.